# How to replace in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace

I can't figure out why this code isn't working.

I want to replace a placeholder with an actual value. Sample code as below:

```
var str = "ID: :ID:";
str.replace(":ID:", 0);
console.log(str);
```

Output:

```
ID: :ID:
```

This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9n79/)

Comment: You have to assign the value back to `str`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.

```
var str = "ID: :ID:";
str = str.replace(":ID:", 0);
console.log(str);
```

[replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

P.s. replace only replaces the first occurrence.
Use replace all if you want to replace all occurrences:
[How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Replace all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: If you pass `find` raw into the `RegExp` constructor, the various regex special characters will cause trouble. For instance, if `find` is "Mr. Smith" you'll replace "Mrs Smith" as well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Your'e right about that, I've searched for a fix and edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Your just replacing the string, but not storing it back. So, it is giving previous string rather than new one.

```
var str = "ID: :ID:";
str = str.replace(":ID:", 0);
console.log(str);
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B9n79/2/

Comment: Note that this will only replace the *first* occurrence of `:ID:`.

Comment: Yes. we can use regular expressions to replace all occurrences

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "ID: :ID:";
str = str.replace(/:ID:/gi, "0");
console.log(str);
```